# what is the replacement for eol character for chef resource?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Due to new version promotion of `line` cookbook, I'm getting an error for resource replace_or_add that it is failing to pass \n due to eol character. Can anyone suggest what is the replacement ?

Answer (score 1):

since chef is built on top of ruby, you can use `$/` ruby new-line [pre-defined variable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html):

> The input record separator, newline by default.